# Can someone explain this ip table

Tags: linux, iptables

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1 -p all -s 192.168.x.y -j SNAT --to-source 1.2.3.4
```

Can someone help me understand this.
I'm really new to linux.

Comment: Where did you find this iptables entry? it doesn't seem to be valid.

Comment: it is valid.. i haved read it but can you explain this iptables command to me? how this works?

Comment: seems like that rule is trying to route trafic to 1.2.3.4?

Comment: can this command can spoof my local ip? i been trying to spoof my ip using iptables but i always fail to do it.

Answer (score 2):

This rule means:

1. make some packets... (which ones? Those having as **source** (*-s*) the IP address 192.168.X.Y, belonging to **every** protocol (*-p all*)
2. ... appear **as though** they originated from address 1.2.3.4 (*-j SNAT --to-source 1.2.3.4*)...
3. ... and this rule must occupy the **first spot** (*-I POSTROUTING 1*) in the *POSTROUTING* queue of the NAT table (*-t nat*).

Basically, rule 3 says where the rule has to be added (and it is correct, *SNAT* rules go to the POSTROUTING queue of the `NAT` table), rule 2 specifies to which packets it applies (basically, to **all** packets from the machine with IP address 192.168.X.Y, and to **all** protocols, TCP, UDP, ICMP,.... **all** of them), and rule 1 specifies which action must be taken, in this case rewrite the packets' headers as though the packets are coming not from IP address 192.168.X.Y, but from IP address 1.2.3.4.

All in all, this is simply a normal NAT rule to allow a machine (192.168.X.Y) to communicate with the Internet even though it has a private, non-routable IP address, endowing it, *de facto*, with  a public routable IP address, 1.2.3.4.

Comment: thank you sir for explaining it to me. this was really my first handling linux and iptables. i was really having a hard time. 

this simple mean that my static ip address was hidden to the web and replace it with 1.2.3.4. it seems like it is most likely a vpn which hide the ip

Comment: @piping It is **not** a VPN hiding an IP address, just a regular *NAT* service, if you do not know what a NAT is read here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation